# Executing the Truffle console script:Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Tags: nodejs, truffle-console

I am trying to execute the following script:

```
module.exports = (callback)=> {
  Message.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
const MyContract = require("~/Truffle programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/contracts/MyContract");
const MyContractTester = artifacts.require("~/Truffle programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/contracts/MyContractTester");
var acc1 = accounts[1]
var acc2 = accounts[2]
const myC = await MyContract.deployed()
const myCT = await MyContractTester.deployed()
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:myC.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei('11')})
myC.sendTo(myCT.address, web3.utils.toWei('3',"ether"), {from:accounts[0]})
myCbal = await web3.eth.getBalance(myC.address)
web3.utils.fromWei(myCbal, "ether")
```

My script is located at:

```
zulfi@lc2530hz:~/Truffle programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle$ pwd
/home/zulfi/Truffle programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle
zulfi@lc2530hz:~/Truffle programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle$ ls my*
myscript.js
```

When I am executing the script on the truffle console, I am getting the following error:

```
truffle(development)> truffle exec myscipt.js
Using network 'development'.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/zulfi/Truffle programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/myscipt.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at Object.file (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/require/require.js:28:1)
    at Object.exec (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/require/require.js:121:1)
    at Promise (internal/util.js:274:30)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at bound exec (internal/util.js:273:12)
    at Object.run (/home/zulfi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.23.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/exec.js:80:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

truffle(development)>
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Isn't the name missing the `r` letter? `myscipt.js`. Another suggestion is to not use a path with spaces.